# Programmatic approach for executing helm charts CLI

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

We are using helm charts to build and deploy applications in kubernetes.
Right now we are doing the same manually.

I would like to write a REST API microservice which will allow us to :

1. Install helm charts from artifactory
2. Check status
3. Upgrade
4. delete
5. Audit

Is anybody tried writing such microservice? 
If yes, sample code snippet would be helpful.

Comment: we could use jenkins with publish over ssh plugin to create a simple job and perform the above-mentioned tasks.

Answer (score 0):

In [helmsman](https://github.com/Praqma/helmsman) I simply wrapped the helm CLI commands. Alternatively, you can communicate with the Tiller over gRPC. Have a look at [Swift](https://github.com/appscode/swift) as an example.